# How to plot arrows which have a gap in the middle?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I want to plot an arrow which shows a long range, so I want to put a gap in its middle part (something like a capacitor in middle). Is there a pre-defined shape for this? The figure shows what I mean.
[image: What I want is this arrow]

Comment: Welcome. Questions on this site should be specific. What web application are you using?

Comment: Thanks @Rubén and sorry for not being clear. I am using draw.io website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is not** a predefined shape for your drawing.

You can build one though, `Group` the elements together, clone it, save it and use it whenever need it.

[image]

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot @marikamitsos. Would you please share the files you build for these arrows?

Comment: Now I get what you mean. I created it.